# Horizontal spacing in nested aligned environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, aligned, hfill

I'm trying to align some columns of a nested `aligned` environment to the right.

This is my current code, and the current result:

```
\begin{align*}
             & 50 & \text{ Rows} \\
    \times\; & 50 & \text{ Columns} \\
    \times\; & \left( \begin{aligned}
             & 1 & \text{ Hills} \\
         +\; & 1 & \text{ Cliffs} \\
         +\; & \left( \begin{aligned}
                     & 51 & r_1 \\
            \times\; & 51 & r_2 \\
            \times\; & 51 & r_3
        \end{aligned} \right) & \text{ Flats}
    \end{aligned} \right) & \text{ Spaces} \\ \\
    \mathbf{\mathlarger{=\quad}} & \mathbf{\mathlarger{\num{331632500}}}
\end{align*}
```

[image: The resulting equation]

I like how `Rows`, `Columns`, and `Spaces` is aligned to the right.

How can I place `Hill`, `Cliffs`, and `Flats` on the right? It doesn't necessarily need to be aligned with the other three words, but I'm looking at the equivalent of what seems would happen if I added `hfill{}` before `Hills`.

In particular, how can I "maximise" the space of a nested `aligned`?

Comment: you can't easily, but what do you want to do with the ) ??? but it in the margin or stroke through the word `Spaces` or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not use an outer `align*`, but `alignedat` that allows to control the space. Adjust the desired central width, here 20% of the global display width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
         & 50 & \text{Rows} \\
\times\: & 50 & \text{Columns} \\
\times\: & \!\left(
             \begin{alignedat}{3}
                   & 1 &\hspace{0.3\displaywidth} && \text{Hills} \\
               +\: & 1 &&& \text{Cliffs} \\
               +\: & \!\left(
                       \begin{aligned}
                                  & 51 & r_1 \\
                         \times\: & 51 & r_2 \\
                         \times\: & 51 & r_3
                       \end{aligned}
                     \right) &&& \text{Flats}
             \end{alignedat}
           \right) & \text{Spaces} \\[4ex]
    ={} & \mathbf{331632500}
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Add `\mathlarger` (if you *really* want it) and `\num`, but take into account that `\mathbf{=}` won't embolden the symbol, you need `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!